# Paypal Button with a custom price

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

I have been give the task of making a PayPal  button which will receive a value based on user choices, but there are so many options in the website that making a button for each choice is unreasonable, I have searched for the answer but either the information was outdated, insecure, or I didn't have the knowledge to understand.

I have seen terms of checkout API,..etc., this and that, but I can't just figure it out.

So, can you guys enlighten me and show me the way.

I know html, php but still kind of a beginner, js sort of.

Comment: `choices` meaning what? Are these products, moral dilemmas, favourite colours? What data are you working with?

Comment: so the client will chose if he wants x , y or z and then select the time he wants it in months , then based on the user choice the button will receive the value that will be calculated based on those choices, i would like to know how and what i need in order to do it , also i want it to be safe , i have been searching but i get nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.write('variable')
```

In JavaScript

Or

```
echo 'variable'
```

In PHP

To change the text of a button to be a certain variable that could depend on the item. JavaScript is easier to setup but PHP could work well if you have a server side data base of items and their prices.

Comment: It's difficult to say anymore without knowing more

Comment: so the client will chose if he wants x , y or z and then select the time he wants it in months , then based on the user choice the button will receive the value that will be calculated based on those choices, i would like to know how and what i need in order to do it , also i want it to be safe , i have been searching but i get nowhere.

Comment: Do you want these calculations to be done server or client side?

Comment: I would like to do it the safer way , so i assume in the server , if its the same i preffer the simple way.(Im sorry that im being kinda of a ignorant)

Comment: I presume that this information​ will need to be sent back to the server anyways so you should use PHP. I would recommend looking up a tutorial for setting up PHP on you server if it isn't already. If it is then use a HTML form with a PHP variable as the button's name.

Comment: [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is an option if you do not wish to reload a page to update content based on the execution of a server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your problem, I'll outline an implementation of a product and quantity system that you can flick through.

You say you have a collection of items, `x, y, x` and provide the option to choose the length of time (in months) the user can have the product.

Let's say, in Javascript, you have the following class for a `Product` object:

```
function Product() = {
    this.Name = "Gaming Computer";
    this.Price = 100; // Per month, in $.
}
```

So a user selects a `Product`, and the `Product` the choose is the `Gaming Computer`. You can test see the name of the product in code by performing:

`console.log(Product.Name)` `// Gaming Computer`

You now have the product, and the associated `property`, `price`. From the inline comment you can see this is in `$, per month`.

Let's assume the user picks `Gaming computer, 6 months`. You don't want to do the following:

```
var month = $('#monthComboBox').val();
if(product.Name == "Gaming Computer" and month == 1) {
   // do stuff
} else if(product.Name == "Gaming Computer" and month == 2) {
// This is getting laborious
} else ....
```

so you would do the following:

`Product.Price * month = totalCost`, which will give you the total to be charged to the user. You can then pass this value to the Paypal button and charge it as needed.

Comment: When im sending the value to the paypal button and charge it , how can i make it safe? so it wont be exploitable

Comment: That's a whole different question regarding the Paypal API rather than generating the value to be charged. Saying that, I can't imagine it'll be too difficult to pass a variable to a Paypal button, your main issue lies with hijacking the payment session which, again, is a very different question.